# Ajax request did not redirect to login page in laravel 8 with jetstream

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

Normally all the page requests, when the session is expired, it gets redirected to the login page .But for an ***ajax request*** it is not redirected and it is failed. Yes **ajax** call will not refresh the page. And there are many ways with which the **Auth** can be checked and perform the redirection.Yet ,is there anything missing in my authentication setup of the **jetstream** to solve this? Or is there any solution to achieve the requirement in a more systematic way with **jetstream** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How are we supposed to know something is missing if you do not supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
Same goes for "it is not redirected and it is failed", how are we supposed to know why it fails if you do not supply a minimal reproducible example?